# Function of White Space in Scala Class Property Setter

Tags: scala

I have the following class:

```
class Thing {
  var privateName = ""
  def name = privateName
  def name_=(newName: String) {
    if (!newName.trim().isEmpty()) {
      privateName = newName.trim()
    }
  }
}
```

If instead I defined the name_ method as (note additional whitespace around "="):

```
def name_ = (newName: String) {
  if (!newName.trim().isEmpty()) {
    privateName = newName.trim()
}
```

then the compiler complains about "value newName" not being found.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to insert white space into the method name? That's not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first your method name is `name_=`, and you declare a parameter as `newName`. You use the java-like syntax for methods returning `Unit`, i.e. defining the method as `{...}` rather than `= ...`.

In the second its name is `name_`, with no parameters, and a definition after the `=`, which starts with a String called `newName`... and it doesn't get any further because that is not a value in scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What was tripping me up was that I did not realize the "=" was part of the method name. I'm just not used to thinking of such symbols as being part of identifiers. I feel a little silly now. :)